# Probability: Poisson Variable, find the lines

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The number of syntax errors committed by an inexperienced computer programmer follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of 0.015 errors per line of code.
Find the minimum number of lines that a program must have so that the probability
of ﬁnding more than one error is at least 90%.

Comment: Thanks. I see the ln coming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outline:** Suppose that a program has $n$ lines. Then the number $X$ of errors in the program has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=n(0.015)$.

We want $\Pr(X\le 1)\le 0.10$. So we want $e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda)\le 0.10$. This inequality does not have a nice algebraic solution for $\lambda$. However, a little calculator experimentation will yield a good estimate for the appropriate $\lambda$, and hence $n$.